# MAPSUI online vector tile source

Tags: xamarin.forms, mapsui

Last I used MAPSUI in an android application (xamarin), vector tiles were not supported. It seems they are now supported through a MbTilesTileSource. This can load a local mbtiles resource, but how can an online tile source like mapbox be used?

This is not something I see represented in the mapsui samples, and the documentation is somewhat lacking still, so I hope someone here might know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector tiles are still not supported in v4. MbTiles can be used to load raster tiles but not vector.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but an answer none the less., and I guess, if anyone knows, it is you. Are there any current plans to add support for vector tiles?

Comment: This is not something we are actively working on at the moment. It will not be part of v5. In v6 we will be focusing on rendering, so, perhaps then.